# What causes a 500 Internal Server Error when making an AJAX request to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am receiving an internal server error, status 500 and I don't know how to troubleshoot. I have added error catch for the ajax call but doesn't tell me much. How do I add code to understand what is going on inside the requesting file? I have tried doing a `var_dump()` but nothing happends.

```
    $('#createpanelbutton').live('click', function(){

        var panelname = $('#panelname').val();
        var user_cat = $('#user_cat').val();
        //var whocan = $('#whocan').val();
        var errors='';
        if(panelname=='')
            errors+='Please enter a Brag Book name.<br/>';
        if(user_cat=='0')
            errors+='Please select a category.<br/>';
        if(errors!=''){
            $('#panel_errors2').html('<span class="panel_brag_errors">'+errors+'</span>');
            return false;
        }else{

         $('#createpanelbutton').val('Creating Brag Book...');
            $.ajax({
                async:false,
                dataType:'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url:baseurl+'createpanel.php',
                error:function(data,status,jqXHR){ alert("handshake didn't go through")},
                data:'name='+encodeURIComponent(panelname)+'&category='+encodeURIComponent(user_cat)+'&collaborator='+encodeURIComponent('me'),
                success:function(response){
                    if(response.status=='success')
                        location.href=response.url;
                    if(response.status=='failure')
                        $('#panel_errors2').html('<span class="panel_brag_errors">'+response.message+'</span>');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Ajax call to to php file createpanel.php:

```
 <?php

include_once('s_header2.php');

if($_POST){

    if($_POST['name'] == ''){
            $msg = "Please enter Brag Book name.";
            $result = array("status"=>'failure', "message"=>$msg);
    }elseif($_POST['category'] == ''){
            $msg = "Please select category.";
            $result = array("status"=>'failure', "message"=>$msg);
    }else{

        $db = Core::getInstance();
        $dbUp = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM ".USERS_PANEL." WHERE user_id = :uID and title = :tit");         
        $result = '2';
        $dbUp->execute(array(':uID'=>$_SESSION['sesuid'],':tit'=>$_POST['name']));
        $result = '3';
        $numrows = $dbUp->rowCount();
        $result = '4';
        if($numrows == 0){
         $result = '5';
        $dbIn = $db->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO ".USERS_PANEL." (`user_id`,`title`,`category_id`,`desc`,`type`,`friend_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

         $dbIn->execute(array($_SESSION['sesuid'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['category'],$_POST['panel_desc'],$_POST['collaborator'],$_POST['jj']));

         $lid = $db->dbh->lastInsertId();            
        //header("Location: ".BASE_URL.addslashes($_POST['bname'])."-".$lid."/");

        $panelurl=BASE_URL.$_POST['name']."-".$lid."/";
        $result = array("status"=>'success', "url"=>$panelurl, "name"=>$_POST['name'], "id"=>$lid);

        }else{              
            $result = array("status"=>'failure', "message"=>'You already have a Brag Book with that name.');
        }
    }

}

echo json_encode($result) ;die;

?>
```

Comment: The *only* place to start debugging a 500 error is the web server's error log.

Comment: Try to post your server error log too, this may help you (and us)

Comment: To see your debug dumps navigate to createpanel.php directly

Comment: A 500 error is thrown by a problem with the actual server as opposed to your PHP code (which would throw a PHP error). As above, best place to check is your server error log. This is stored in different places depending on your OS/Server Software etc.

Comment: @DanGreaves 500 simply means the server returned a 500 status code. PHP can do that as well depending on how your error handling is setup.

Comment: A 500 server error could be any number of things, but it certainly isn't related to jQuery in any way. It can sometimes be a PHP syntax error, or an error in your .htaccess or php.ini files, or some other server config problem. The server error log will give you an exact description of the error.

Comment: @KevinB Very true. Although not a usual setup, that could be the case.

Comment: @SDC: Not directly, but have you seen KevinB's answer? This is an AJAX request... a POST var is being used unconditionally in a database query which has not been sent in the (jQuery) request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post var isn't being sent by your ajax request: `$_POST['panel_desc']`

Comment: It was `$_Post['panel_desc']` and `$_POST['jj']`. I left these two fields out for the initial setup of the panel. Looks like PDO won't move forward on null or empty fields. Thanks!

Comment: Check the post here http://www.developersnote.com/2014/01/solved-jquery-ajax-500-internal-server.html[link]

Answer (score 5):

Internal server errors are one of the many [HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and the origin is on the server side (PHP most likely).

Check your webserver log. The origin of your 500 error is there :)